# How to expire fragment cache for objects index on object update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1, fragment-caching

I'm fragment-caching this fragment:

```
<% cache('fragment-id') do %>
    <div id="fragment-id">
        <%= render @object %>
    </div> 
<% end %>
```

Now, obviously, I need to expire that cache every time an *object* is updated (speaking from the db perspective).

So I'm supposed to put this line:

```
expire_fragment('fragment-id')
```

...here and there among the controllers, every time an action *updates* (or *saves*) an *object*.

But I'm wondering if there is a **DRYer way** to do this, like writing some sort of hook in the *object* model (/app/models/object.rb) which triggers the expire_fragment command on every update (or save).

Is it possible?

EDIT#1:

Maybe I can just overwrite the save method in the object model like this:

```
def save
    expire_fragment('fragment-id')
    super
end
```

But, in order for this to work properly, I must be sure that the "save" method is called also by **all** the other saving methods like *update_attributes*, *save!*, etc. Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can observe your object with Sweeper, and inside it add hook on update. Read about sweepers [there](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sweepers).